# Firebase cloud functions stopped working - event.data undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have some cloud functionsbut they suddenly stopped working, now I'm getting event.data undefined

```
exports.newMessageReceived = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}')
 .onWrite((event) => {

    if (event.data.previous.exists() || !event.data.exists() ) {
        //Do nothing if data is edited or deleted
        console.log('Message edited or deleted - skip');
        return;
    }
   ...
}
```

And I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'previous' of undefined
```

This is how it is defined [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions#handle_event_data). There was any change in firebase cloud functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloud functions were updated to version 1.0, you can check here for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database

Regarding the question, you need to change the code into this:

```
exports.newMessageReceived = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}').onWrite((change,context) => {

if (change.before.exists() || !change.after.exists() ) {
    //Do nothing if data is edited or deleted
    console.log('Message edited or deleted - skip');
    return;
  }

}
```

`onWrite` now has two parameters `change` and `context`. `Change` has `before` and `after` properties, and `before` is equivalent to `previous`

Also `change` and `before` can use the methods listed here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot

Comment: Is there a way to install 0.9.1 version of firebase?

Comment: it is easier to update though.. I'm not sure but try this then `npm install firebase-functions@0.9.1 --save` the version should change in your package.json. But you may get other problems if you downgrade, not really sure..

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.

This is a firebase documentation showing the changes that have been made on the new v1

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff