# reference error event is not defined node.js

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-notifications

I'm working with Notifications but the Notification is not working and getting this error, I am new to this so i can't fully understand this and getting tilted by the error. Any help would be appreciated, I don't find any related solutions about this

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined
at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:9:31)
at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:744:24
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

and Here is my index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = 

 functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {

    const user_id = event.params.user_id;
    const notification = event.params.notification;

    console.log('We have a notification to send to: ', user_id);

        if(!event.data.val())
        {
            return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from database: ', notification_id);
        }

        const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`);
        return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

            const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;

            console.log('You have new Notification from: ', from_user_id);

            const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`Users/${from_user_id}/name`).once('value');
            const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

            return Promise.all([userQuery, deviceToken]).then(result => {


                const userName = result[0].val();
                const token_id = result[1].val();

                    const payload = {
                      notification: {
                        title: "Message Request",
                        body: `${userName} has sent you a Message Request`,
                        icon: "logo.png",
                        click_action: "com.example.gab.quadrantms_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
                    },
                    data : {
                        from_user_id : from_user_id
                    }
                };

                return admin.messaging().sendtoDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>{

                    console.log('This was the Notification Feature');
                    return true;
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53006628/how-can-i-send-firebase-notifications-using-cloudfunctions-on-firebase-database/53007337#53007337

Comment: Your code is using the pre-1.0 syntax for Cloud Functions. Please study the migration guide here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff, specifically the section https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#event_parameter_split_into_data_and_context

Comment: Also see these previous questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49647257, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018686, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52213392, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52058241, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50660963

Comment: I'm sorry Sir I am a totally beginner so I find it really hard to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error says, `event` isn't defined anywhere. It looks like you should be using `context` instead.

```
const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification = context.params.notification;
```

Here are the docs for `EventContext`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext

And `RefBuilder.onWrite`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onWrite

Comment: So should I change all events to context?

Comment: Or you can change the argument name `.onWrite((change, event) => {`